# How to add WordPress loop in function?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to add WordPress loop in function. I tried adding this code in function but it's not working. Using `global $post;` also not take any effect. Can anyone please tell me how to add loop in function?

**Loop:**

```
$term_lists = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'vendors', array("fields" => "all"));

foreach($term_lists as $term_singles) {

echo $custotaxos = $term_singles->slug."<br>"; //do something here

$myposts = get_posts(array(
    'showposts' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'vendor',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
        'taxonomy' => 'vendors',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => array($term_singles->name))
    ))
);

foreach ($myposts as $mypost) {
      echo $mypost->post_title . '<br/>';
      echo  $mypost->ID . '<br/>';
echo get_permalink($mypost->ID);

echo "<br>";
}

}
```

**Function:**

```
function woo_custom_product_tab_content() {

}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_custom_product_tab' );
```

Comment: Your function is `woo_custom_product_tab_content()`, and your function in filter is `woo_custom_product_tab`. The hook wants to add `woo_custom_product_tab`, and here is not such function. Just place: `add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_custom_product_tab_content' );` and you'll see your code. Also use `add_action`, not `add_filter` if you want to echo something out.

Comment: Its still not working. If I echo something, then its work, but Loop is not working.

Comment: When you do a `print_r($term_lists);` does anything happen? Your loop is within a loop, and that's not good. Try defining an empty array `$custotaxos_name = array();` outside first foreach, and inside the first foreach add `$custotaxos_name[] = $term_singles->name;`. Remove the post loop from the first foreach, and then in the `get_posts` for the `terms` just use `$custotaxos_name`. And the second foreach should be for posts only.